# Access violation writing location inserting to array

Tags: c, winapi

I am getting Access violation error from the debugger, but I really have no idea why. I suspect that it would be something really stupid.
I have an array of directory entries:

```c
typedef struct dirEntry{
    TCHAR fileName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD fileSizeLow;
    DWORD fileSizeHigh;
} dirEntry;

DWORD bufferSize = MEM_SIZE; //MEM_SIZE = 100
DWORD bufferPosition = 0;
dirEntry* dirBuffer;

dirBuffer = (dirEntry*) malloc(bufferSize*sizeof(dirEntry));
```

Then I pass it to a function `ListDirectory(_T("D:\\books\\*"), dirBuffer, &bufferSize, &bufferPosition)`

Inside the function I retrieve information about the files inside, but when I call this:

```c
dirBuffer[*bufferPosition].fileSizeLow = dataFound.nFileSizeLow;
_tcscpy(dirBuffer[*bufferPosition].fileName, dataFound.cFileName);
*bufferPosition++;
```

The first line produces an exception. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Code of `ListDirectory` as demanded: http://pastebin.com/ScbcqX7p

Comment: Is bufferPosition a valid number? I.e. is it smaller than bufferSize?
Also, has dataFound been initialized?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mentioning that in the question, I have added it to the snippet.

Comment: Yes, they are valid numbers. As for dataFound - it is indeed valid, as I can print the contents to the console.

Comment: Maybe the code for `ListDirectory` would help

Comment: What is the value of 'bufferPosition'?

Comment: Only other thing I can think of would be to check if dirBuffer is non null. Just before your line that fails, add this:

    if(dirBuffer == NULL)
        printf("Non initialized\n");

Comment: @NickLH I have it there, I just didn't think it was necessary to include it in the post.

Comment: In case of error, you free your buffer allocated outside in called function. Don't do that. Also, if it happens and you call the `ListDirectory` again (why do you have the `realloc` there?) it will crash where it crashes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The value of `bufferPosition` is zero, since it crashes right on the first entry.

Comment: @ruslik Well I do not know how many entries are there, so if there are more than a hundred I need to expand the array.

Comment: I mean the one before the loop.

Comment: Ah, right. That doesn't belong there. Sorry, it's kinda late in here and I'm somewhat sleepy.

Comment: @AlexandarŽivkovič: Well then that's your problem. You can't dereference a NULL pointer. (You have `*bufferPosition`.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think you misunderstood me. The value of `bufferPosition` variable is 0, so that it points to the first member of the array. But I pass it by reference, so the pointer is not NULL, it points to the `bufferPosition` variable initialized in main function.

Comment: Can you paste the code that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*bufferPosition++` does not do what you think it does. It dereferences `bufferPosition`, then increments the pointer, not the value pointed to. You probably wanted `(*bufferPosition)++`, which increments the pointed-to value.

Mind you, it's not clear why you are passing `bufferPosition` and `bufferSize` by address, since they are useless to the caller, since `ListDirectory` frees the data the variables refer to.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. As with the passing by address - I have removed the call to free from error handling in the function. And I need it like this because I need to work with the array outside the function.

Comment: Then you also need to pass the updated array back to the caller.

Comment: Can you please help with one more thing?
Allocation of the dirBuffer stayed the same, I just added & operator when passing it and modified the code.
Is this wrong:  

`(*dirBuffer)[*bufferPosition].fileSizeLow = dataFound.nFileSizeLow;`?  
Because it's still doing the same thing.